# Python D-Bus on Windows with MiNGW

Tags: python, windows, compilation, mingw, dbus

I'm following [this tutorial](http://poquitopicante.blogspot.ca/2012/07/building-dbus-python-on-windows-with.html) to get my Python application (which use DBus) working on windows.
I'am at the step `Build DBus` (using MiNGW and therefore gcc). 
So, here we are at my problem: There is an error while compiling:

[image]

As you can see, it's just a syntax problem...
I've tried to fix it directly into the concerned file, but lt-dbus-monitor.c seems to be a generated one and i've not been able to find which generates it (The makefile is so obfuscated).

May someone have a solution to this ?

Comment: I'll add that i've tried different versions of D-Bus, I still get this error

Answer (score 1):

All right, i feel a bit stupid...
For those who will be interested: I've just replaced spaces from "scratch MiNGW DBus" with underscores...
I guess it does not like spaces in folder name, obviously.